# What am i missing unity/c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so i am trying to code a unity game where you can build a LEGO like bench with several stones. But i am new to coding so i got a lot of errors.

1. The else in the end is triggered everytime and i dont know why, even if an else if is true before.
2. the platzierteSteine int will not increment and always 0 when i tried to print it out.
3. Is the "||" condition correctly used?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GrabScript : MonoBehaviour {
    /// <summary>
    /// GameObject, das den Spieler-Controller beschreibt
    /// </summary>
    [SerializeField] GameObject controller;

    int[] steineInEbene = {2, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    int platzierteSteine = 0;
    int ebene = 1;

    public GameObject falsch;
    public GameObject richtig;

    int zähler = 0;

    /// <summary>
    /// Start is called before the first frame update
    /// </summary>
    void Start() {  

        // Fehlermeldung wird ausgeblendet
        falsch.SetActive(false);
        // Siegermeldung wird ausgeblendet
        richtig.SetActive(false);

        }

    /// <summary>
    /// Update is called once per frame
    /// </summary>
    void Update() {

        // Falls die Distanz zu diesem Objekt passt, weitermachen. Sonst passiert nichts.
        if (Vector3.Distance(controller.transform.position, this.transform.position) < 2.5f) {
            // Prüfe, ob die Taste E gedrückt wird
            // Starte halten des Stein
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
            {
                // Parent-Objekt festlegen. Siehe Konzept des Scenegraphen aus der Vorlesung!
                this.transform.parent = controller.transform.GetChild(0).transform;
                // Während des Haltens sollen keine Kräfte, Kollisionen usw. wirken
                this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
                this.GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = false;
                controller.GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = true;

            }
            
            // Wenn der Controller auf der Platte steht packt er die Steine dahin wo sie hingehören 
            if (400 <= controller.transform.position.x && controller.transform.position.x <= 410 && 
                540 <= controller.transform.position.z && controller.transform.position.z <= 550) 
            {

                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
                {

                    if(this.transform.name == "1x2" && ebene == 1) 
                    {
                        this.transform.position = new Vector3(407.97f, 0.44f, 547.08f);
                        this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(270, 0, 0);
                        platzierteSteine++;
                        if(platzierteSteine == steineInEbene[0]) { ebene++; platzierteSteine = 0; } 
                    }

                    else if(this.transform.name == "1x22" && ebene == 1) 
                    {
                        this.transform.position = new Vector3(407.97f, 0.44f, 542.87f);
                        this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(270, 0, 0);
                        platzierteSteine++;
                        if(platzierteSteine == steineInEbene[0]) { ebene++; platzierteSteine = 0; } 
                    }

                    else if((this.transform.name == "1x1" || this.transform.name == "1x12" || this.transform.name == "1x13" || this.transform.name == "1x14") && ebene == 2) 
                    {
                        if(zähler == 0) {
                            this.transform.position = new Vector3(407.97f, 1.04f, 547.08f);
                        }
                        else if(zähler == 1) {
                            this.transform.position = new Vector3(407.97f, 1.04f, 542.87f);
                        }
                        this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(270, 0, 0);
                        zähler++;
                        platzierteSteine++;
                        if(platzierteSteine == steineInEbene[1]) { ebene++; platzierteSteine = 0; } 
                    }

                /*  else if(this.transform.name == "1x12" && ebene == 2) 
                    {
                        this.transform.position = new Vector3(407.97f, 1.04f, 542.87f);
                        this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(270, 0, 0);
                        platzierteSteine++;
                        if(platzierteSteine == steineInEbene[1]) { ebene++; platzierteSteine = 0; } 
                    }
                */
                    else if(this.transform.name == "Schräg" && ebene == 2) 
                    {
                        this.transform.position = new Vector3(407.37f, 1.04f, 547.08f);
                        this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(270, 0, 90);
                        platzierteSteine++;
                        if(platzierteSteine == steineInEbene[1]) { ebene++; platzierteSteine = 0; } 
                    }

                    else if(this.transform.name == "Schräg2" && ebene == 2) 
                    {
                        this.transform.position = new Vector3(407.37f, 1.04f, 542.87f);
                        this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(270, 0, 90);
                        platzierteSteine++;
                        if(platzierteSteine == steineInEbene[1]) { ebene++; platzierteSteine = 0; }
                    }

                    else if((this.transform.name == "1x1" || this.transform.name == "1x12" || this.transform.name == "1x13" || this.transform.name == "1x14") && ebene == 3)  
                    {
                        if(zähler == 2) {
                            this.transform.position = new Vector3(407.97f, 1.64f, 547.08f);
                        }
                        else if(zähler == 3) {
                            this.transform.position = new Vector3(407.97f, 1.64f, 542.87f);
                        }
                        this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(270, 0, 0);
                        zähler++;
                        platzierteSteine++;
                        if(platzierteSteine == steineInEbene[2]) { ebene++; platzierteSteine = 0; }
                    }

                /*  else if(this.transform.name == "1x13" && ebene == 3) 
                    {
                        this.transform.position = new Vector3(407.97f, 1.64f, 542.87f);
                        this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(270, 0, 0);
                        platzierteSteine++;
                        if(platzierteSteine == steineInEbene[2]) { ebene++; platzierteSteine = 0; } 
                    }
                */
                    else if(this.transform.name == "sitz" && ebene == 3) 
                    {
                        this.transform.position = new Vector3(407.37f, 1.44f, 547.08f);
                        this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(270, 0, 0);
                        platzierteSteine++;
                        if(platzierteSteine == steineInEbene[2]) { ebene++; platzierteSteine = 0; } 
                    }

                    else if(this.transform.name == "1x1 mit Noppe 2" && ebene == 4) 
                    {
                        this.transform.position = new Vector3(407.969f, 2.24f, 547.081f);
                        this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(270, 0, 0);
                        platzierteSteine++;
                        if(platzierteSteine == steineInEbene[3]) { ebene++; platzierteSteine = 0; }
                    }

                    else if(this.transform.name == "1x1 mit Noppe" && ebene == 4) 
                    {
                        this.transform.position = new Vector3(407.969f, 2.24f, 542.87f);
                        this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(270, 0, 0);
                        platzierteSteine++;
                        if(platzierteSteine == steineInEbene[3]) { ebene++; platzierteSteine = 0; }
                    }

                    else if(this.transform.name == "rückseite" && ebene == 5) 
                    {
                        this.transform.position = new Vector3(407.54f, 2.24f, 547.08f);
                        this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 270, 90);
                        platzierteSteine++;
                        if(platzierteSteine == steineInEbene[4]) { ebene++; platzierteSteine = 0; richtig.SetActive(true); }
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        falsch.SetActive(true); 
                        StartCoroutine("Wait"); 
                    }
                    
                this.transform.parent = null;
                this.GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = true;
                controller.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;    
                    
                }
            }

            // Wenn der Controller nicht auf der Platte steht lässt er die Steine einfach fallen
            else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F)) { 

                this.transform.parent = null;
                this.GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = true;
                this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
                controller.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;

            }
        }
    }

    
    IEnumerator Wait() 
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3.5f);
        falsch.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.- The else in the end is triggered everytime and i dont know why, even if an else if is true before.

It is inside the `Update`. As the comment in the code it is colled every frame, so what is inside this, is continously being called.

2.- the platzierteSteine int will not increment and always 0 when i tried to print it out.

That is because any f the conditions of your `if` where `platzierteSteine++;` is is being met. You need to debug and check taht out. Check [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) to see how to debug, set breakpoints and check the value of your conditions to see if they are bieng met and why.

3.- Is the "||" condition correctly used?

That is the "or" logical operator. It is correctly used regarding compilation. However is the logic you expect is not occurring try debugginh that out.